# Телеграм бот на вебхуках. Как это работает?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Начал делать телеграм боты по туториалам. Сделал достаточное их количество, чтобы понять как работают все методы. До этого использовал aiogram. Потом прочитал официальную документацию Telegram Bot API. Так я понял, что использовать библиотеки типа aiogram или telebot не обязательно. Можно все сделать через http-запросы. В моем понимании: если ботом пользуюсь только я, то все хорошо: один запрос–один ответ. Но как все это работает если бот используют много пользователей? Из документации узнал про вебхуки. Но ничего не понял. Что и где можно прочитать про это в целом, и как это использовать при создании телеграм бота в частности. Буду признателен за какие-то ссылки на ресурсы или еще что-то. Опять-таки в этой теме я полный ноль.

Comment: делал вот так [ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/post/655965/). У меня работало норм

Comment: Спасибо! Еще вопрос. Я заметил что методы и классы (типы), описанные в официальной документации телеграм и  в aiogram отличаются. Есть ли какой-то гайд, типа читшит со сравнением (сопоставлением). Или я уже чушь несу D:

Comment: Просто смотрите доку aiogram'a